# Mongodb query not working with string

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using the `mongodb` package on my Nodejs app. I try to remove an nested object. It work when I put a nested object. It does not work when I put the string into the condition and I don't understand why. Can someone help me?

That doesn't work:

```
var tmp = 'records.' + j + '.domains';
records.update({'email': '<removed>'}, {'$pull': {tmp: {'_id': req.params.dn}}});
```

That work:

```
records.update({'email': '<removed>'}, {'$pull': {'records.1.domain': {'_id': req.params.dn}}});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the following syntax:

```
var tmp_key = 'records.' + j + '.domains';
var tmp_value = {'_id': req.params.dn};
var query = {};
query[tmp_key] = tmp_value;
records.update({'email': '<removed>'}, {'$pull': query});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you cannot use a variable as key in object literal. Instead construct the object dynamically using `obj[tmp] = nested_obj`.